# How to have tabmix plus not adapt bookmarklet names as tab title?

Tags: firefox-extensions, browser-tabs, bookmarklet

Tabmix Plus has the very nice option to let tabs display the bookmark title instead of the actual `document.title`. Unfortunately, this also includes bookmarklets, i.e. if I use a bookmarklet (a bookmark starting with `javascript:`) Tabmix Plus changes the tab title to the bookmarklet title. How can this be fixed without disabling this otherwise very useful option?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue using Tab Mix Plus v0.5.0.4 on Firefox 54.0.1 32-bit and 64-bit. The current tab title changes as soon as I execute some bookmarklets. What is curious is that the Firefox windows title is not impacted.

I have contacted the Tab Mix Plus developer in order to ask for support.
I will update this answer as soon as I have some news.

**Edit**: on 19/11/2017, the dev contacted me and I communicated all the technical info to him. He says he will see what he can do.

**Edit**: as Tab Mix Plus is not compatible with FF57+, I think the developer doesn't want to put further effort in it. I don't use Tab Mix Plus anymore, I have found alternatives.